# Searching on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, search

**Why are the instant question recommendations that appear when asking a question so much better/faster than the results from performing an actual query in the search field?**

I understand that I can use quotes and tags to improve my search results. But if I simply type in "*Detecting the end of a for loop in php*" it returns "*0 results*". If, as recommended, I wrap the query in quotes I get "*0 results*". Let's simplify the query then and ask "*for loop php*", "*0 Results*". If I perform the same query in quotation marks with the tag [php] I start to get results, but not very good ones. This being a pretty vague query it returns vague results. In contrast if I click 'Ask Question' and start typing my query "Detecting the end of a for loop php.." I get instant, precise results.

Now I know that next to the query results you can click 'Advanced Search Tips' which gives you things like is:question and is:answer...but what does this mean? Do I prepend my question with "is:" or "is:question", both, either/or? SO offers things like tags and other various elements to assist in queries, but I will get a far more precise results if I simply click 'Ask Question' and start typing my question. Why isn't this query power available in the standard search field? Is it and am I simply not using it correctly?

How do **YOU** search on Stack Overflow? Please help me and the community become better Stack Overflow users. While I feel like this is a total noob question, I bet other people have experienced it as well so perhaps it's worthy of documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with our query parsing before the handoff to the lucene layer - it's now fixed in a build that just rolled out.

You'll now see there are 92 results for the query [Detecting the end of a for loop in php](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Detecting%20the%20end%20of%20a%20for%20loop%20in%20php).

Comment: thanks for the rapid response.

Comment: Looks like I caused there to be a duplicate by asking the question on META that was being migrated as well. oops.